# Enabling 401 Challenge responses when using WebAuthenticationConfiguration

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, rest, wcf-rest-contrib

I have a very simple WCF4 Restful web service which uses WcfRestContrib to allow custom Basic Authentication. It works great when the client preemptively supplies a username and password but if they don't it returns a 400 Bad Request response rather than challenging the client to supply credentials (through a 401 response).

The service is using the declarative approach to implementing WcfRestContrib by decorating the necessary classes with Attributes. Here is my ServiceContract declaration:

```
// Standard attributes here
[WebAuthenticationConfiguration(typeof(WebBasicAuthenticationHandler),
                                typeof(SecurityValidator),
                                false,
                                "SearchService")
]
public class SearchService
```

Which only has one very simple operation:

```
// Standard attributes here
[OperationAuthentication]
SearchResponse Fetch(SearchRequest request)
```

And my `UserNamePasswordValidator` looks like (though it probably doesn't matter since it only gets called when credentials are passed):

```
public override void Validate(string userName, string password)
{
    // TODO: Insert login validation logic here.

    // To indicate login failure, throw a FaultException
    // throw new FaultException("Unknown Username or Incorrect Password");

    // Just return to indicate that the username and password are valid
    return;
}
```

I tried to debug WcfRestContrib and found that the `WebBasicAuthenticationHandler` class is throwing a `BasicAuthorizationException` (which is only caught in framework code), however, for some reason it isn't transforming the exception into a 401.

Based on what I've read on the [WcfRestContrib github site](https://github.com/mikeobrien/WcfRestContrib), there is [an issue posted by its author (Mike O'Brian)](https://github.com/mikeobrien/WcfRestContrib/issues/5) saying that he'd like to see it return anything *other than* a 401 which I read as it currently returns the 401 challenge.

If this functionality is there then what am I missing, or am I doing something else wrong?

**UPDATE**

If there is not a way to do this with WcfRestContrib, is there an alternative way to achieve this (beyond using the standard Windows-based Basic Authentication in IIS)? I'm open to any (other) alternative solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. I needed to decorate my ServiceContract with the `ErrorHandlerAttribute`:

```
// Standard attributes here
[WebAuthenticationConfiguration(typeof(WebBasicAuthenticationHandler),
                            typeof(SecurityValidator),
                            false,
                            "SearchService"),
 ErrorHandler(typeof(WebErrorHandler))]
public class SearchService
```

Just by adding the `[ErrorHandler(typeof(WebErrorHandler))]` attribute to the service makes all of the magic happen. I knew it had to be something simple, just wish I would have seen it before flattening my forehead on my desk.